# Creating complex path structure in linux

Tags: bash

I am having trouble creating the following directory structure. It is to test a scanner program to see if it can handle it.

- Start inside `/data/`
- Inside `/data/` there are 2 sub-directories. `/data/sub1` and `/data/sub2`

Now, this gets complex :)

- In each of the sub-directories there are  2 more sub-directories. For first sub: `/data/sub1/sub1/ and /data/sub1/sub2` and for second sub `/data/sub2/sub1/ and /data/sub2/sub2`
- ... this goes on to a depth of 16 levels, with a total directory of `65,536`.

What I have so far, this only creates 1 subdirectory inside `/data/`, 16 folders deep. I am thinking of using the following script recursively for the subdirectories created along the way. And for the subdirectories it then creates. And so on. But I can't imagine scripting it.

```
count=0;
folder=$(printf "Folder%02dB" $count); 
mkdir -p $folder;
while [ $count -lt 16 ]; do 
    ((count=$count+1));
    folder=$(printf "Folder%02dB" $count); 
    mkdir -p $folder;
    cd $folder;
done
```

Anyone has any ideas on how to create such directory structure? How to proceed? Thanks!

Comment: You seem to have picked up the habit of terminating every line with a `;`, that's not how Bash works.

Comment: Doesn't *hurt* anything... /shrug

Answer (score 1):

Recursion is a good way to do this.

```
#! /bin/bash

godeep()
{
    if [ $1 -lt 16 ]
    then
        ((level = $1 + 1))
        mkdir sub1
        cd sub1
        godeep $level
        cd ..
        mkdir sub2
        cd sub2
        godeep $level
        cd ..
    fi
}

godeep 1
~
```

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't be incorporating `$count` in the folder name. That's just used to count the recursion depth.

Simplest would be to define a function to create a single level, and call it recursively.

```
create_folders() {
    if (( $1 > 16 )); then
        return
    fi
    depth=$(($1 + 1))
    mkdir sub1; (cd sub1; create_folders $depth)
    mkdir sub2; (cd sub2; create_folders $depth)
}

create_folders 1
```

Using `()` around the `cd` and recursive call keeps them from affecting the working directory and variables in the current call.